# Issue with serialising and deserialising Singleton instances of classes with ArrayList fields

Tags: java, serialization, singleton, deserialization

Presently, I am writing a Java application that uses the Singleton pattern and serialisation. I have a dedicated serialiser class that serialises and deserialises an object to and from a given file path. One of my objects is serialised and deserialised without issue: I make some changes to my application's state while it's open, then close the application, and those changes are still there when I reopen it. However, this does not work with another one of my objects, even though as far as I can tell there is no major difference between them that should cause this to be the case.

Here is the code for my Serialiser class:

```
public static Boolean serialise(Object target, String filePath){
    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);){

        objectOut.writeObject(target);
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialiser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialiser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public static Object deserialise(String filePath){
    try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);){
        Object readObject = objectIn.readObject();
        return readObject;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialiser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant code for my objects. First, the one that works:

```
public class AccountManager implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "data//account_manager.ser";

    private static AccountManager instance;
    private ArrayList<Account> accounts = null;

    private AccountManager(){
        accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static AccountManager getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = (AccountManager)Serialiser.deserialise(FILE_PATH);
            if (instance == null){
                instance = new AccountManager();
                Serialiser.serialise(instance, FILE_PATH);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

And now the one that does not work:

```
public class MessageManager implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String FILE_PATH = "data//message_manager.ser";

private static MessageManager instance = null;
private ArrayList<Message> messages = null;

private MessageManager(){
    messages = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static MessageManager getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = (MessageManager)Serialiser.deserialise(FILE_PATH);
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new MessageManager();
            Serialiser.serialise(instance, FILE_PATH);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Essentially, both classes work the same way: they store an list of objects of a certain type and provide access to and perform operations on the contents of their respective lists. When the Singleton instance of the classes are accessed, it checks if it could deserialise an instance from a file. If it can't it instantiates a new one and serialises it. Again, this works for one, AccountManager, but not for the other, MessageManager. That is, if create new Account object and store it using the AccountManager while the application is running, it will still be there if I restart the application. The same is not true for MessageManager and Message objects.

When a new Account is created, the instance, and presumably its associated fields, i.e. the *accounts* list are serialised.

```
public Account createAccount(String password, String givenName, String surname, String address, Gender gender, LocalDate dateOfBirth){
        String id = IDGenerator.getInstance().generateID(AccountType.PATIENT, accounts);
        Account createdAccount = null;

        if (id != null){
            createdAccount = new PatientAccount(id, password, givenName, surname, address, gender, dateOfBirth);
            if (createdAccount != null){
                accounts.add(createdAccount);
                Serialiser.serialise(instance, FILE_PATH);
            }
            return createdAccount;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In MessageManager, when a new Message instance is added its list, and the instance, and again, presumably its list, are serialised:

```
public Boolean sendMessage(Message message){
    if (messages.add(message)){
        Serialiser.serialise(instance, FILE_PATH);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Both Account and Message implement Serializable, and both have serialVersionUIDs. I do not get any NotSerializable exceptions.

Any help would in fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated. If necessary, I can provide more of my application's code.

Comment: Singletons and (de)serilization don't work well together. I would move all the data of a singleton class into an own internal data class that can be easily (de)serialized.

Comment: @Robert But it works correctly for AccountManager. Why do you think it works for that one, but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. My issue was in a different part of my application. Essentially, I had believed that MessageManager was not be serialised because I couldn't get the data I was expecting back from it. It turns out the issue was in the method that returned the data: I was using an object reference to identify what data to return. Of course, deserialisation creates new instances, so, after recreating my objects, I could not longer access data identified by an old instance.

To fix my issue, I used a different means of identifying data: a string property whose value would be the same across instances, before and after deserialisation.

Thank you to everyone who looked at my question and/or attempted to answer it.